# Graphical Login wont show up after installing GTK+ 3.0 ( The GUI creation software )

Tags: boot, login, shutdown, lightdm, brightness

I am a complete newbie to Linux .I managed to install GTK+ 3.0 in my Ubuntu Laptop and after a short session afterwards i tried to turn the system Off . But i noticed a small problem with the shutdown button as i clicked shutdown 4 times , yet it didnt do anything . So i turned off my laptop using `shutdown` command .

When i tried to turn my laptop ON the next time , Black screens seemed to flicker on and off regularly even before the login screen. I tried rebooting . Changing the display manager to gdm3 from lightdm only made it worse . I tried to press `Ctrl+Alt+F1..2.7` only to find that same black screen . Suddenly i observed that the black screen actually had the login prompt , but the brightness was so low that i couldnt see . I tried increasing the brightness with function shortcut keys in vain . I managed to execute a few commands after looking few similar answers . But none seemed to fix this issue . I also tried logging in with GRUB and executing the commands 
       `sudo service lightdm stop`
       `sudo service lightdm start`

I also noticed a few errors such as `VCE error <-22>` `Backlight controller missing` while booting . I tried to searching with these errors but i couldnt find a solution . I have a LiveUSB of the same Ubuntu version . Can anyone suggest a fix ? Thanks in advance !

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1566
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]       
Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] (rev 05)
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 156b
00:02.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
00:08.0 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1537
00:10.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller (rev 11)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller (rev 39)
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller (rev 02)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 11)
00:14.7 SD Host controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SD Flash Controller (rev 01)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1580
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1581
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1582
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1583
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1584
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1585
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330] (rev ff)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6164 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 20)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
```

Model Name : Lenovo G50-45
RAM : 8GB
Processor : AMD A8
HDD : 1 TB

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, especially if you have a newer pc, the ubuntu video drivers don't fully work for your graphics card. You could try installing them using the instructions found at the Ubuntu wiki for installing Nvidia video drivers below.

1. Go to Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers

   Once the drivers are downloaded and installed, reboot your computer.

[How to install Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

Comment: Thanks for answering . But i mentioned newbie in the sense that i dont know much about most commands . I have been using Ubuntu for 3 months and have already installed drivers for ATI for games like DOTA 2

Comment: Do you get a gui at all anymore? If you do, try going to software & updates, additional drivers to install the nvidia ones. It will search your computer and make a recommendation of ones to install.

Comment: I dont get gui unless i use my Live USB to 'Try with Ubuntu' , which i guess will not solve this problem here .

Comment: How did you change the display manager? Did you just select lightdm in the drop down box? Ctrl+Alt+F2 (or F7, technically) should take you back to the gui if it is still up and active. That is a special key combination to switch between terminals, which there are ten.

Comment: I used _sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm/gdm3_ using the terminal i mentioned which i barely saw !

Comment: What if you ran 'sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop' or 'sudo dkpg-reconfigure ubuntu-gnome-desktop', will that revert you to the gnome desktop successfully? However, you would need to boot into your live usb, mount your old installation partition with 'sudo mount </dev/sdaX> /mnt/oldsystem', chroot into it by running 'sudo chroot </mnt/oldsystem>' and then you can install things just like you are logged into your old system's terminal.  This tutorial helps cover it: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

Comment: I tried booting by using LiveUSB and using all the mount processes , but i was greeted with the error _apt cannot lock the administration lock process_ and it also asked _Are you root ?_ eventhough i am clearly logged in as root .I also tested running the reconfigure command without LiveUSB , and i got an error that gnome-desktop is not installed . When i tried to install i got the same error .

Comment: I tried again with LiveUSB to reinstall _lightdm_ , as i suspected the problem must have been with it . When i changed it to _gdm3_ now , i got the problem that i once had which lead to loading screen and crashed visually . But this time i got the error _temporary failure resolving 'in.archive.ubuntu.com'_ . Have you seen such errors ? By the way , i got frustated and reinstalled ubuntu without losing /home folder , but still the problem seems to persist .

Comment: I think there is an issue with your computer's graphics card, and ubuntu. For a last ditch effort, you could try adding 'nomodeset' to the grub kernel line when you boot by pressing 'e' to edit the grub boot line when booting your computer and the operating system kernel selecting screen appears. You could also try a ubuntu disk with another desktop environment if lightdm worked ok for you and Gnome didn't. I would also recommend you try out another distro's live cd, such as Fedora, to see if it has better support out of the box for your graphics card.

Comment: After a lot of frustation i reinstalled ubuntu again , but this time i formatted root folder and left the home untouched and i was finally able to get back a _working ubuntu_. i figured it was _lightdm_'s problem but i couldnt reinstall lightdm again . Dont know how but i managed to screw both the display managers in two different situations .Solutions are welcome still because i found this was a unique problem . I spent days searching for the solution and nothing worked . So let others get some help . Thanks for helping .

Comment: You are welcome. Good job on sticking with it! :) Have a great day.